# Rails - How to create advanced arrays that sums columns?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do I create an array that  sums the column earn on a date.

So it would output like:

```
[<sum of 'earn' where dato=2011-02-14>, <sum of 'earn' where dato=2011-02-15>]
```

And how to create a pointstart, that finds the last date.

My table

```
id  virksomhed  dato                   earn     
9   Euroads     2011-02-15 00:00:00     4 
10  Euroads     2011-02-15 00:00:00     4   
11  Iqmedier    2011-02-15 00:00:00     2   
12  Iqmedier    2011-02-15 00:00:00     3   
12  Iqmedier    2011-02-14 00:00:00     3  

{
        name: "Indtjening",
        pointInterval: <%= 1.day * 1000 %>,
        pointStart: How to create point start,
        data: 
      },
       {
        name: "Iqmedier",
        color: '#DBD200',
        pointInterval: <%= 1.day * 1000 %>,
        pointStart: How to create point start,
        data: <%= Reklamer.where(:virksomhed => 'Iqmedier').all.map(&:earn) %>
      }
      ,
       {
        name: "Euroads",
        color: '#1B7B94',
        pointInterval: <%= 1.day.to_i * 1000 %>,
        pointStart: How to create point start,
        data: <%= Reklamer.where(:virksomhed => 'Euroads').all.map(&:earn) %>
      }
```

Comment: For anyone else staring at this, I believe the result array is effectively `[<sum of 'earn' where dato=2011-02-14>, <sum of 'earn' where dato=201-02-15>]`

Comment: Instead of an array, it seems better a hash of pairs dato/sum_of_earns. Even with a certain ordered if necessary.

Comment: It should be an array or the chart wont work. How do I select the last date? need it to pointstart

Comment: @Rails: of course you can transform the hash into an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Reklamer.sum(:earn, :group => :dato)
#<OrderedHash { 2011-02-14 00:00:00 => 3, 2011-02-15 00:00:00 => 13}>
```

Comment: How do I create the hash to an array?

Comment: @Rails: Reklamer.sum(:earn, :group => :dato).values #=> [3, 13]. Use :order => :dato (for example) in sum to specify the order, otherwise it's just random.

Answer (score 0):

```
Model.find(:all, :select => 'sum(earn) AS earn', :group => 'dato').map(&:earn)
```

Comment: And how do i create an pointstart like <%= Reklamer.where(:dato => 'last.date').to_i * 1000 %>

Comment: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
....append= ( Reklamer.find((:all, :select => 'sum(earn) AS ear...

Comment: It should order be date. Like [<sum of 'earn' where dato=2011-02-14>, <sum of 'earn' where dato=2011-02-15>]

Comment: `Model.find(:all, :select => 'sum(earn) AS earn', :group => 'dato', :order => 'dato ASC').map(&:earn)`